# Reset password display layout

Tags: php, html

This my code for a reset password page. Everything works fine when i have tried it without any styling but when i have integrated in my original webpage nothing is displayed.

```html
<?php

require("../dbconnect.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>ipv6 | Reset Password</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Top content -->
        <div class="top-content">
         
            <div class="inner-bg">
                <div class="container" >
                    <div class="row">
     <?php
     if (isset($_GET['code'])){
 $get_email=$_GET['email'];
 $get_code=$_GET['code'];
 
 $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE email='$get_email'");
 
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
 {
  $db_code = $row['pass_reset'];
  $db_email=$row['email'];
 }
 if ($get_email == $db_email && $get_code == $db_code)
 {
  echo "
  <form action ='pass_reset_complete.php?code=$get_code' method='POST'>
  PASSOWRD= <input type='password' name='newpwd'/><br>
  Confirm PASSOWRD= <input type='password' name='newpwd1'/><p>
  <input type= 'hidden' name='email' value='$db_email'/>
  
  
  </form>
  ";
 }

 else
     echo "
                        <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box'>
                         <div class='form-top'>
                          <div class='form-top-left'>
                           <h3>Reset Password</h3>
         <hr>
                              <p>Enter your email address and we’ll send you an email with instructions to reset your password.</p>
         <form name='forgot.php' method='post' class='login-form'>
                        <div class='form-group'>
                         
                            <input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email Address...' class='form-username form-control' id='form-username' onblur='check();'>
                           </div>
                           <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' name='submit' class='btn btn-success'>
                                    
                       </form>
                          </div>
                       
                            </div>
                            <div class='form-bottom' style='background-color:#fafafa'>
                       <p >If you don't receive an email from us within a few minutes, check your spam filter as sometimes they end up in there. The email will be from help@teamtreehouse.com.</p>
                      </div>
                        </div> ";
      
      if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 
 $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE email='$email'");
 $numrow=mysql_num_rows($query);
 
 if($numrow!=0){
  $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
   $db_email=$row['email'];
  
  if($email== $db_email){
   $code=rand(10000,1000000);
   
   //email msg
   
   $to=$db_email;
   $subject="Password Reset";
   $body="
   This is an automated email.Please do not reply to this.
   
   Click the link below or paste it into your browser
   
   http://localhost/forgot/forgot_pass.php?code=$code&email=$email 
   
   ";
   mysql_query("UPDATE member SET pass_reset='$code' WHERE email='$email'");
   
   mail($to,$subject,$body,"FROM:ipv6@learning.org");
   echo "CHECK YOUR MAIL";
  }
  else{
   echo "email incorrect";
  }
 }
 else{
  echo "THAT DOES NoT EXIST";
 }
 
 }
     } 

      ?>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Have i made some error in terms of double quotes or any other wrong attempt please suggest

Comment: Please place this code `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your page and let me know what it print?

Comment: This script is unreadable, using **removed** functions and open for SQL injections.

Comment: i find an issue, you are using post method and getting email values by using GET method, how it possible?? $get_email=$_GET['email'];

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd here is the message:Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\IPv6eLearningToolv3\dbconnect.php on line 18

Comment: @Nia, So please try with use [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php), this is your solution.

Comment: @devpro the get id for the update password section. As i have mentioned evrything works fine if i remove all the html and styling and keep only the forms. But when i have styled it according to my website it just does not work

Comment: same issue with `mysqli_connect`

Comment: yes becuase of your html issue, check my solution. and use {} in else condition.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd no this time no error just same blank page

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` should display error if any?

Comment: added it just after `<?php` but no error message just that blank page with my background page. The forms are long lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the {} brackets in else condition.

```
if ($get_email == $db_email && $get_code == $db_code)
{
    // your stuff
}
else{ // **you missed these brackets**
    // your stuff
}
```

**Side Note:** And i suggest you to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` because `mysql_*` has deprecated and not available in PHP 7.

Comment: even with the brackets nothing happens

Comment: paste this in your file at top: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); @Nia

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100040/discussion-between-devpro-and-nia).

Comment: @Nia: in this url, you do not have $_GET['code'] ... and your main check is $_GET['code']...

Comment: see our chat i have explained it there